# Favorites overview in Gogs

Tags: favorites

In [Gogs](https://gogs.io/) I can star repositories to add them to my favorites.

But I cannot find some sort of overview of my favorites. Is there such a thing in Gogs? Without that I don't understand the purpuse of this feature.

[image]